# Eccentered Circles - determine space between circle at a given location

Tags: geometry

I need to figure out a way of calculating the dimensions x and y as shown on the attached image. I know the angles (in the example the inner circle is broken into 6 - 60 degree angles). I also know the diameters of both circles.

I have tried a bunch of approaches but I think I am missing some simple point that is not letting me see the solution.

David

[image: Eccentered circles]

Comment: Thank you - it is very obvious now. I think I was trying to make it more complicated and as a result missed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $O_1$ and $O_2$ be the centres of the small and large circles, and let $r_1$ and $r_2$ be their radii. Let $P$ be the point on the large circle in the top right (so $x$ measures the distance from the small circle to $P$).

Now consider the triangle $PO_1O_2$. Its side lengths are $r_2-r_1$, $r_2$, and $r_1+x$. The angle $\angle PO_1O_2$ is known (in this case, $60^\circ$). Now use the Cosine Law to find $x$.

Comment: Thank you - it is very obvious now. I think I was trying to make it more complicated and as a result missed this.

Comment: @Dcuthill My pleasure. As a general rule, appeal to whatever fundamental properties you can for a given shape. In the case of circles, this means finding a way to use their centre and radius.

Comment: @Théophile Just a quick question? Is the sum of $x$ and $y$ a constant?

Comment: @imranfat Yes, $x$ and $y$ are both constants here, since the diagram is fixed, although of course they depend on the radii of the circles. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Théophile What I meant was, if the radii are given, is $x+y$ constant independent from the angle? (The line of which $x$ and $y$ are part, can freely rotate about the center of the smaller circle and what that constant be $d1-d2$?)

Comment: @imranfat Ah, I see. No, they are very much dependent on the angle. To see this, look at the extreme case where $r_1 \approx 0$. Then as the line through $O_1$ rotates, $x+y$ will vary between approximately $0$ and $2r_2$.

Answer (score 0):

choose the units so that the smaller circle has radius $1$ and the bigger one has radius $R.$ let the center of the smaller circle be $O,$ the common point of contact be $A,$ and the point $C$ such that $AC$ is the diameter of the bigger circle. the points $B, D$ are on the bigger circle and $BOD$ is a line.

applying the cosine rule to the triangle $AOB$ gives $$AB^2 = 1 + (1+x)^2 + (1+x)$$

applying the cosine rule to the triangle $COD$ gives $$CD^2 = (2R-1)^2 + (1+y)^2 -(2R-1)(y+1)$$

the two triangles $AOB, DOC$ are similar so that $$\dfrac{1}{1+y} =\dfrac{1+x}{2R-1} = \dfrac{BA}{CD}  \tag 1$$

we can solve $(1)$ for $x$ and $y.$