# Eccentered circles - determine space between 2 circles at any point around circumference of inner circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Several months ago I asked the question referenced here .... [Eccentered Circles - determine space between circle at a given location](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1136934/eccentered-circles-determine-space-between-circle-at-a-given-location)

For this same question I now need to figure out a more generic approach where the angle is not $60$ degrees but now could be anything from $0$ to $359$ degrees with $0$ always being the point at which the $2$ circles intersect (contact one another). How could I figure out what $x$ is in this situation?

David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

the simpler way is to parametrize the segment of leght  $d=\overline {PQ}$ (see the figure) by means of the central angle $\theta=\angle POM$.

From the figure we have:

$\overline{OP}=R \quad \overline{CQ}=r \quad \overline{OC}=R-r$

and using he cosine rule we have:
$$
\overline{PC}=d+r=\sqrt{R^2+(R-r)^2-2R(R-r)\cos \theta}
$$
from which we can find $d$ as a function of $\theta$.

---

If you want to use the angle $\phi=\angle PCM$ as independet variable, than you can find $d$ from (cosine rule for $\overline {OP}$):
$$
R^2=(R-r)^2+(r+d)^2+2(R-r)(r+d)\cos \phi
$$

But it is a bit more intricate.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the angle I am interested in is ∠PCM. How would that change things?

Comment: The function is not so simple. You can find it using $\dfrac{r+d}{\sin \theta}=\dfrac{R}{\sin(\pi-\phi)}$ where $\phi = \angle PCM$ and substituting in my formula. But maybe that there is some simpler way.. .

Comment: @Dcuthill: I've added something to my answer. :)

Comment: Thank you - so using your most recent addition to the post I would need to solve a quadratic equation to determine d. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, and be careful to the improper solutions ( i've corrected a sign typo).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome ! don't forget to accept if you like :)